# How to pause/stop video in actually time (like 3.00 secs)

Tags: javascript, html, timer, html5-video, pause

I was wondering is there possible to **pause the video** in **actually time** ?

I tested and video always pause at `x.xxx` not `x.00`

```
video.load();
video.play();

video.ontimeupdate = function(){
   if(this.currentTime >= 3) {
      video.pause();
   }
};
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/4gh7a058/

Any trick ?

*PS: Should be good performance as possible also*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot guarantee that the video will stop at an exact moment in time.

According to the [documentation](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#mediacontroller) for media controller:

> Every 15 to 250ms, or whenever the MediaController’s media controller
>   position changes, whichever happens least often, the user agent must
>   queue a task to fire a simple event named timeupdate at the
>   MediaController.

timeupdate event will fire when it can using the least often scenario. It does not give you the option to choose the exact fire times for the updates.

A trick you could do is the following: Remove the timeupdate event, set your own interval and using that check the time.

```
setInterval(function () {
   var ct = video.currentTime;
   current_time_el.innerHTML = 'Current time : ' + ct;
   if(ct >= 3) {
      video.pause();
   }
}, 40);
```

This approach will force you to be more careful with your code though. (e.g clean up your interval with clearInterval() when it is not needed any more)

Comment: seems like I have to use `setInterval` :(